# Customizing the look of tabView headers

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am looking forward to customize the look of tabView component. I need to change the color of tab headers(& if possible, 2 different colors for 2 different headers). I tried to do so by specifying the CSS rules through styleClass attribute for tabView but failed to see desired results.

How I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces components get the look&feel from a css theme. You can either:

- Build your own theme with the desired colors with [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/),
- Change the style classes for your theme manually. Style classes for each Primefaces component are listed in the Primefaces documentation. Since the doc is not free for most recent Primefaces version 2.2 I can only help your with the classes from Primefaces 2.1: .ui-tabs, .ui-tabs-nav, .ui-tabs-panel. Notice that there might be more style classes applying to the tab view inherited from other components. Check html source of the tabView to get all applying classes.
- Use the `style` or `styleClasses` attribute as described in your answer and overwrite the theme classes with the [`!important` declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules)

Comment: I do have the user guide but I couldnt find any information related as how to change the style classes acc to my specific theme. Also I tried customizing through styleClass(option 3) but failed to see results

Comment: While working with styleClasses, I could customize the look of text however I couldn't change the on-hover color of the tabs.

Comment: @Marcos: Option 3 seems to be buggy. See Cagatay's answer. The style classes must be somewhere in the css files of your theme.

Answer (score 2):

3.0.M2 has titleStyle and titleStyleClass attributes for tab component.

http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=892

Comment: is this version released ? I could see only the 3.0m1 at download page.