# Including help icon or help button on primefaces tabView header

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to include help icon or button inside primefaces tabView header beside the tabs

```
<p:tabView >
            <p:tab title="title1">
            <p:tab title="title2">
            <p:tab title="title3">
            <span  class="ui-icon-help" style="position: absolute; right: 6px;"  id="desc"  />
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: Which type of help icon? do look at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/tooltip/tooltipOptions.xhtml

Comment: @ArgaPK i need to add (question mark icon) at the far right within the TabView header then using tooltip for it as :

tab1 |  tab2  |  tab3 |                                                                           ?   |

Comment: the question is already answered, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288784/customizing-the-look-of-tabview-headers